# Rotate a vertical rectangle to an horizontal one with Python Kivy - How?

Tags: python, graphics, kivy, widget, kivy-language

I'm trying to program a game with Python Kivy, only get stuck on one thing, will be a simple question, but I have not found a solution anywhere.

I want the line in the middle of the screen (see picture attached) to be horizontal instead of vertical, meaning from left to right. Is there any method to rotate this? Or what do I have to change in the script?

[Change vertical line to horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyMIx.png)

Here is my script that creates the graphic:

```
<PongGame>:
    canvas:
       Rectangle:
          pos:    self.center_x - 5, 0
          size: 10, self.height
```

I would appreciate any help. Keep in mind, I'm still pretty much a beginner.

Best regards,

PyBeginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do that is using `kv`, like this:

```
<PongGame>:
    rotate: False  # property to control rotation
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:  (0, self.center_y - 5) if self.rotate else (self.center_x - 5, 0)
            size: (self.width, 10) if self.rotate else (10, self.height)
```

This code define a property (`rotate`) of `PongGame` that controls the rotation. If `rotate` is `False`, then your original `Rectangle` is drawn, but if `rotate` is `True`, then a rotated `Rectangle` is drawn. A similar result could be attained using python code, but then you must write more code (bindings) to handle situations where the user changes the size of the `PongGame`. Doing it all in `kv` lets kivy handle those bindings.

Once you have this code in place, you can just rotate the `PongGame` using a method such as:

```
def rotate(self, dt):
    self.root.rotate = not self.root.rotate
```

In your `PongApp`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. It works great!